# Open / View a PDF file after creating it on google sheets by selecting "yes" from a dialog box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

the following code allows me to create a PDF file from a spreadsheet. As you can see it has two dialog boxes. The first dialog box is only to notify the user that the file has been created, the second dialog box, in my original code, was to ask if the user wanted to email the PDF file. However on this occasion I do not want the function of sending email, I want to be able to see/view/preview the PDF file. I can't make the script show me the PDF file that was just created (view / preview the file). I hope you can help me since I have not found any help related to this topic. Thanks on advance.

```
    function googlesheetToPDF(){  

    var id = '1C8DZEQwSv6wjq6kr1TSWldUuiThWsjXCT6d6aghmkPu';  // Dummy Id

    var index = 0;  

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();


    var hoja = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var columnas = hoja.getRange("M1:P1");
    hoja.hideColumn(columnas);

    var HojaActiva = ss.getSheetByName('Hoja 1');

    // variables to construct the name of the file
    var fecha = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
    var cotizacionNo = HojaActiva.getRange("I2").getDisplayValue();
    var cliente = HojaActiva.getRange("F8").getValue();
    var correo = HojaActiva.getRange("F10").getValue();

    var nombre = cotizacionNo +' - ' + cliente + ' - ' + fecha + '.pdf';  // Name of the PDF

    SpreadsheetApp.flush();


    var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'
    + id
    + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
    + '&size=letter'
    + '&portrait=true'
    + '&fitw=true'
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'
    + '&gridlines=false'
    + '&fzr=true'
    + '&gid=
    + index;

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
    var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName(nombre).getAs('application/pdf');

    var folderid = '14DmJKycu_ysc0ewkWGzvItOFdMx47i4b'; // Dummy Id
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
    folder.createFile(pdf);

    var hoja = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var columnas = hoja.getRange("M1:P1");
    hoja.unhideColumn(columnas);

    var archivo = docurl.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
    var attach = {fileName:nombre,content:archivo, mimeType:'application/pdf'};


    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('New document created in' + ' ' + folder);

    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var response = ui.alert('Do you want to view the PDF file?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

    if (response == ui.Button.YES) {


    //Here is where I´m stuck   


    } else {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
    }; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you solve your issue. I created a custom Dialog box where I built the HTML template and then changed some parameters to be able to open the PDF file using this function:

```
// Generate a custom HTML to open the PDF
function showPdfFile(pdfFile) {
  // Create the template html
  var htmlString = '<!DOCTYPE html>'
    + '<html> <head> <base target="_top"></head>'
    + '<body>' 
    + '<input type="button" value="Yes" onClick="window.open(##URL## , ##TYPE##, width=800, height=600); google.script.host.close();"/>' 
    + '<input type="button" value="No" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />'
    + '</body> </html>';
  
  // Change the parameters inside the window.open method 
  htmlString = htmlString.replace("##URL##", "'" + pdfFile.getUrl() + "'");
  htmlString = htmlString.replace("##TYPE##", "'_blank'");
 
  // Create the output window 
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(htmlString)
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  
  // Show the Window
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Do you want to view the PDF file?');
}
```

And your `googlesheetToPDF` function now would look like this:

```
function googlesheetToPDF(){  

  var id = 'your-ID';  // Dummy ID
  var index = 0;  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var hoja = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var columnas = hoja.getRange("M1:P1");
  hoja.hideColumn(columnas);

  var HojaActiva = ss.getSheetByName('Hoja 1');

  // variables to construct the name of the file
  var fecha = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "dd/MM/yy HH:mm");
  var cotizacionNo = HojaActiva.getRange("I2").getDisplayValue();
  var cliente = HojaActiva.getRange("F8").getValue();
  var correo = HojaActiva.getRange("F10").getValue();

  var nombre = cotizacionNo +' - ' + cliente + ' - ' + fecha + '.pdf';  // Name of the PDF
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var theurl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'
    + id + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + '&size=letter' + '&portrait=true' + '&fitw=true' 
    + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' + '&gridlines=false' + '&fzr=true'
    + '&gid='+ index;

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var docurl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(theurl, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token } });
  var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName(nombre).getAs('application/pdf');

  var folderid = 'your-ID'; // Dummy Id
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
  var pdfFile = folder.createFile(pdf);

  var hoja = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var columnas = hoja.getRange("M1:P1");
  hoja.unhideColumn(columnas);

  var archivo = docurl.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:nombre,content:archivo, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('New document created in' + ' ' + folder);
  
  // Instead of an if/else statement, call this function 
  showPdfFile(pdfFile);
    
}
```

### Notice

You would need to use CSS to give some style to the buttons generated in the HTML template.

### Docs

To know more about custom Dialog boxes check these Docs:

- [Custom dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)
- [createHtmlOutput()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createhtmloutput)
- [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Thank you very much, it is exactly what I wanted to do, it works perfectly.